# Forfiles don't memorize Variable by SET

Tags: file, batch-file, forfiles

I use an `.xlsx` file that grows progressively for updates. The syntax:

```
FORFILES /P  C:\TMP /S /M *.XLSX /C "cmd /c echo @path = @fsize"
```

and everything works fine.

I would like to store the size of `@FSIZE` in a variable to retrieve the data in a comparison but that doesn't seem to work.

If I use:

```
FORFILES /P  C:\TMP /S /M *.XLSX /C "cmd /c SET MySize=@fsize"
```

does not store the value. In fact, if you try to type `SET %MySize%` from the prompt it tells you that the value is `null`. Very frustrating.

It would be nice to be able to run:

```
FORFILES /P  C:\TMP /S /M *.XLSX /C "cmd /c IF %MySize% LSS @fsize DEL @path
```

I would like to retrieve the value of `@fsize` for future comparisons.
If the `.XLSX` files are smaller than `@fsize`, then delete them.

Comment: I have typing Incorrect  syntax

Comment: ```cmd /c SET MySize=@fsize``` runs the `SET` command inside a `cmd` instance and `/c`loses. As soon as it closes the variable is disposed of.

Comment: What can you teach me to recover the value without losing it? Thank you

Comment: Use a `for /f` loop, or save the value to a file and read it back in with `set /p`. Both techniques have been used many hundreds of times on this site. Please use the search facility to locate and learn from one or more of them.

Comment: Of course you could dispense with the very inefficient `forfiles.exe` utility completely, and instead use either a `for /r` loop, or possibly a `for /f` loop with the `dir` command. Then grab the size using the appropriate modifier.

Comment: It works great. Thank you very much and sorry for asking. I'm curious to learn and it often comes naturally to me to ask!